# I want to pass multiple parameters in post method using ajax.

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is the code. Here I want to pass item id , stock quantity and price using ajax in post method. Its really great if someone can help me . Thankss inadvance

```
         function update_item(item_id, sellingPrice,stockQty){

           // alert (sellingPrice);
            var item = item_id;
            var sellingPrice = sellingPrice;
            var stockQty = stockQty;

            //var temp = "#"+item_id;
            //var temp1 = "'"+temp+"'";
            alert ("hii");

             $.ajax({


                        url : 'UpdateItem2.php',
                        method : 'POST',
                        data : {"item=" : item + "sellingPrice=" : sellingPrice + "stockQty=" : stockQty},
                        alert (item);
                        success : function($result){
                            alert("Stock upated successfully");




                        }

                    });

        }

   </script>
```

Comment: What's going wrong? Are errors reported? Does *anything* happen?

Comment: `data : {"item=" : item` .... remove those `=` unless the host expects the parameter name to have them

Comment: actually - the whole `data` object is wrong, I just noticed the `+` in it ... as a developer, the first place to look is the browser **developer** tools console for errors - which you will have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an alert() inside an object declaration, that wont work. Also you need to comer separate each element of your data object like this:

```
data: {"foo": "bar", "bar": "foo"}
```

Comment: I committed the alert and change the data as you said. But still I can't pass values. Do you have any suggestions

Comment: Check the network tab of your browsers debug tools to see if the request is sent, also you can try adding: print_r($_POST); die(); at the top of your UpdateItem2.php file to see what data gets there.

Comment: Thanks alot problem sorted out